# "Let me can" vs "Let I can"?which should I use?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

For example:

> There is a way ***let I can*** ask why unclear?

vs

> There is a way ***let me can*** ask why unclear?

Which is better English sentence(text)?

[context link](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4542/how-do-when-i-cant-findunderstand-how-unclear-on-my-question)

Comment: I don't understand either the questions being presented here as examples, or the information being sought by this ELL post. If the post itself isn't straightforward Off Topic ***proofreading***, you need to explain exactly what the example questions are supposed to be asking.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm sorry,I feel [The Photon's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/137788/55501) is very perfect or useful ,but I'm still can't understand how make this ell question to more clear.maybe can you tell me more about this ell question?please.

Comment: The reason this question has been closed is because we don't understand what your example question means (what exactly does the questioner not know, and hope to find out by asking?). If you ***edit*** your question text to explain as best you can what the questioner is thinking, and what kind of "answer" he's hoping to get, your question may be answered by others in ways which make things clearer for you. Are you perhaps trying to ask something like *How can I ask for clarification if I am still unclear about something after reading an ELL answer?* Note that I'm just guessing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these examples are hard to understand. But not because of *I* vs. *me*.

1. You need to say what it is that's unclear.
2. The word *let* needs a subject. Something has to let the other thing do something.
3. It would be more clear to invert subject and verb to express a question ("Is there a way...?" instead of "There is a way...")

The closest I can come up with to your examples using the word *let*, that makes grammatical sense, is

> Is there a process that lets me ask why something is unclear?

But that's very wordy. An easier version to read might be,

> How can I ask why my question is unclear?"

Comment: Then,what is difference between `Is there a way...`and`There is a way...`?maybe should I post a new question for this comment?

Comment: "Is there a way" is the usual way to word a question. "There is a way.." expresses a statement of fact, not a question. In speech, you could use intonation to indicate a question with the "there is" word order. In writing the question mark indicates this intonation but it's clearer to just use the normal question word order unless you're quoting something that was originally said aloud.